# Godaddy wildcard certificate not working on AppHarbor

Tags: ssl, certificate, appharbor

I bought a wildcard certificate from GoDaddy, I logged into AppHarbor and created the certificate. I also uploaded the intermediate certificate.  Everything worked fine, but whenever I go to my site (https://edificio.bo.administratuvivienda.com) I receive the following error on IE.

---

```
This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to edificio.bo.administratuvivienda.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.

What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is
trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.

Technical Details
 edificio.bo.administratuvivienda.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.administratuvivienda.com , administratuvivienda.com  

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an AppHarbor issue, and it's the intended mode of operation for wildcard certificates. A wildcard certificate for *.example.com will only be valid for foo.example.com and bar.example.com and similar, and *not* for foo.bar.example.com.